# Why does my iOS app not run on my iPod touch?

Tags: ios

I have written a universal iOS-App that runs fine on my iPhone and iPad, but not on my good old iPod touch. X-code does not even transfer the binary. It just says

> finnished running programname on devicename

The deployment target is 4.2. (The iPod touch runs 4.2.1 and it has 2.1 GB of free space).

How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know your specific iPod model but I had this problem and it sounds like an armv6 / armv7 issue that started coming around recently with the latest XCode update.  I pulled my hair out for ages on this one.

Make sure that your build is armv6 - you might need to physically type in "armv6" as supported near the top of your build settings otherwise it is only compiling for armv7 devices.

Comment: Thanks! I hard typed armv6 and now it loads. But does this mean that my app will run less efficient on newer hardware? Can I somehow upload two versions of the app to App Store?

Comment: I don't believe that's a problem. You should be supporting both armv6 and armv7 and the device will run what is most appropriate.  It would be pretty inelegant for Apple to expect you to build two different apps to support 2 different architectures - not really their style :)