# This App Is Incompatible With This iPod touch

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-4.2, ipod-touch, incompatibility

I have developed an app that required iOS >= 4.0. But when I download it from App Store by using my iPod touch 2 (iOS 4.2.1), it says "This App Is Incompatible With This iPod touch". I don't know why. And when I use this iPod touch to run the app through Xcode, it also don't run on my iPod touch. How can I debug this error?

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218679/why-does-my-ios-app-not-run-on-my-ipod-touch) and my app build settings show that "Architectures" is "Standard(armv7)" and "Valid Architectures" is "armv6 armv7", I wondered if it's wrong.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?  If it is 4.x then you need to add armv6 with armv7 as your architecture for iTouch's to work:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198676/warning-iphone-apps-should-include-an-armv6-architecture-even-with-build-config

Comment: I have read that page and tried each method, but unfortunately It donesn't work to my issue. It only say nothing but "Finished running $APP_NAME on $IPOD_NAME", OMG.

Comment: Barring the armv6 thing, does your app actually require options your iPod touch doesn't have like Gyro, Camera, or Multitasking?

Comment: +NJones No, it's just a very common app that donesn't use features like Gyro, Camera or Multitasking.

Answer (score 0):

How to add support for `iOS 4.2`, `armv6` in `Xcode 4.2`. I have tried to make this easy to follow.

Set your deployment target to 4.2 or earlier:
[image]
Modify Architectures to include `armv6` like so:
1)Select Other,
[image]
2) Click on the "+" button,
[image]
3) Type in "armv6",
[image]
4) Click done.

Then remove armv7 from required device capabilities by clicking the "-" button in that row.

[image]
I personally use this method constantly to run apps on my iPod touch 2nd gen with the newest Xcode.(at this point Build 4D502).

In fact the project that I used for this example now runs on that iPod.

Comment: I am so sorry, but it cannot solve my problem. The console prints nothing and the device doesn't run as before. Maybe I should not test my app on iPod touch 2, maybe it's so old and Xcode 4.2 is so new.

Comment: Your iPod is not to old. My iPod is the same as yours running 4.2.1 and I am using the most recent non-beta release of Xcode (build 4D502) just updated last night from (4D199). I will edit my answer soon to be more clear.

Comment: I have tried this before you edited, but it couldn't run on my ipod touch. Thank you all the same.

Comment: Your iTouch is not too old.  I just released my game today actually that works on the same iTouch versions and newer devices using Xcode 4.2

Comment: Make sure that `armv6` is included in both `Architectures` & `Valid Architectures` in both your project & your target.